# Can you upgrade Postresql-server directly from 9.2 to 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, rhel

Can you upgrade Postresql-server directly from 9.2 to 9.6? (Running on RHEL 7)

Comment: define "directly"? See also: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/upgrading.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html

> pg_upgrade **supports upgrades from 8.4.X** and later to the current major
>   release of PostgreSQL, including snapshot and alpha releases.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html

> Because pg_dump is used to transfer data to newer versions of
>   PostgreSQL, the output of pg_dump can be expected to load into
>   PostgreSQL server versions newer than pg_dump's version. pg_dump can
>   also dump from PostgreSQL servers older than its own version.
>   (Currently, **servers back to version 7.0 are supported**.) However,
>   pg_dump cannot dump from PostgreSQL servers newer than its own major
>   version; it will refuse to even try, rather than risk making an
>   invalid dump.

ephasis mine